# Does using a glyph of warding as a spell glyph take two spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, traps

The description of glyph of warding is vague about how spell glyphs are made, it says that you are casting the spell to be stored as part of casting this spell, and whether this takes a spell slot for both castings is unspecified as far as I can tell.

> You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower by casting it as part of creating the glyph.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### It does take two spell slots.

The first line of the spell describes what happens when you cast the Glyph of Warding:

> When you cast this spell, you inscribe a glyph that harms other creatures...

Later, it specifies that if you choose the spell glyph option, you cast the spell you choose to store (emphasis added):

> You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by **casting** it as part of creating the glyph.

PHB 201 specifies that when the "casting" wording is used, it uses up a spell slot:

> When a character casts a spell, he or she expends a slot of that spell’s level or higher, effectively “filling” a slot with the spell.

This interpretation is consistent with other game mechanics that are more explicit about how this works. For example, contingency works this way:

> You cast that spell, called the contingent spell, as part of casting contingency, expending Spell Slots for both, but the contingent spell doesn't come into effect.

or the ring of spell storing:

> Any creature can Cast a Spell of 1st through 5th level into the ring by touching the ring as the spell is cast. The spell has no effect, other than to be stored in the ring.

Comment: PHB 201 calls out that casting does not always require a slot:
**Some characters and monsters have special abilities that let them cast spells without using spell slots.** I read this to mean that Glyph requires 1 spell slot to cast Glyph and another way to cast a spell, the most obvious is a spell slot, but also open to scrolls, wands, staves, rods, abilities, magic items, etc.  The most important aspect is that the Glyph's spell slot must be equal to or higher than the spell level of the other spell.

Comment: I think you could also argue that Ring of Spell Storing could store up to a 5th level Glyph and you could avoid using slots altogether.

Comment: I think that your conclusion is correct, but it feels like the Contingency spell is a problematic example. After all, in that case you cast the second spell "as part of" the casting of the main spell, but the text explicitly spells out that you must expend spell slots for both. That could be seen as evidence that you don't need to expend a second spell slot for Spell Glyph