# Can you store a Spell Glyph with a spell scroll of a prepared spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

This is a follow-up to a previous question of mine ([Can you store a Spell Glyph with a spell scroll of a non-prepared spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133831/can-you-store-a-spell-glyph-with-a-spell-scroll-of-a-non-prepared-spell)) where it was established that you do need to have a spell prepared in order to be able to spell glyph it.

This question is a slight twist to the previous one: if you do have the spell prepared, but also have a spell scroll of the same spell, are you able to make the Spell Glyph by using the spell scroll instead of a spell slot?

Ex: Bob the 5th level Wizard having "Haste" and "Glyph of Warding" prepared, and in possession of a Spell Scroll of Haste, willing to cast a Spell Glyph of Haste, but using the scroll instead of a spell slot, therefore only using a slot and a scroll instead of two slots.

A supporting argument for a "Yes" answer would be that the Glyph of Warding's Spell Glyph section does not mention the mandatory use of a spell slot for the spell to glyph, just that it must be prepared.

> You can store a prepared spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph by casting it as part of creating the glyph.

Comment: Related: [Does using a glyph of warding as a spell glyph take two spell slots?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105621)

Answer (score 5):

### Sure! But it would destroy the scroll

In a [previous answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/133833/30218) to another question, it points out that spells cast from magical items and prepared spells are in different categories. However, it's possible to have them in both categories in the same time. You could be able to cast the spell Haste via the Spell Scroll magic item, and you could also have it "prepared".

Glyph of Warding's text states (PHB, p. 246, bold added):

> You can store a **prepared spell** of 3rd level or lower in the glyph **by casting it** as part of creating the glyph.

So you are required to do two things:

1. Have the spell prepared
2. Cast the spell

But you are not required by the text to cast the spell via your spell slots. As long as it is prepared and you cast it (and it is of the appropriate level), you have satisfied Glyph of Warding's requirements.

It would be a somewhat odd choice to use a Spell Scroll for this undertaking though, since spell slots are a renewable resource while Spell Scrolls are single use resources only. After all, the rules on Spell Scrolls state (DMG, p. 200, bold added):

> Once the **spell is cast,** the words on the scroll fade, and the scroll itself crumbles to dust.

And as has been stated above, **you must cast the spell to store it in the Glyph of Warding. As such, the scroll would crumble into dust** when you completed your casting of Glyph of Warding (it would not wait until the Glyph actually activated).

But if you find yourself in a situation where this strategy is desirable (such as when you only have one third level [spell slot](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105621/does-using-a-glyph-of-warding-as-a-spell-glyph-take-two-spell-slots), but also have an hour to cast Glyph of Warding, or if you are casting a spell via an item that uses charges to cast spells and prefer to spend a charge to a slot [thanks to MarkTO for suggesting this]), it should work.

Comment: This means that if you can cast a spell via an item, such as a ring, wand, or rod, then that would work, too, and cost you neither a spell slot nor a scroll, just a charge

Comment: @MarkTO Sure. As long as you also have that spell "prepared" in the typical sense (fixed in mind and ready to be cast with spell slots).

Comment: This is basically what I was saying, but you seemed to clarify better. My only caveat is that I was saying the scroll wouldn't be consumed unless the prepared spell required a material component (which the scroll takes the place of), but your explanation works just as well. Thanks for making a coherent answer.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme If you're wondering about a potential use case for this, it's that in Adventurers league play, it is possible to buy Spell Scrolls of up to 5th level with gold, and at 4th Tier of play, you end up having lots of gold. Now, imagine having a simulacrum of a wizard (or other spellcaster who prepares its spells), so you don't want to use its spell slots, but you can give it spell scrolls so that it can make glyphs for you. very convoluted, I know.

Answer (score -2):

The Glyph of Warding Spell Glyph option notes:

> You can store a prepared spell of 3rd or lower level in the glyph by casting it [the prepared spell] as part of casting the glyph...

There are further limitations to the spell to be cast with the glyph, but they are irrelevant to the question.

So it should be established that you are required to have the spell prepared, and must cast it as part of the Spell Glyph. The Spell Glyph never says you must expend a spell slot for the second spell (unlike Contingency, which explicitely states it expends a slot for both Contingency and the contingent spell). As such, using a scroll for the Spell Glyph, while fully possible, is pointless, as it wouldn't even be used up. If you have the spell prepared (a pre-req for Spell Glyph), you cast Glyph of Warding with that spell, but don't expend a spell slot (or scroll) to do so. You're able to use the spell because it's prepared, not because of a spell slot or scroll.

I would say yes, you can have a scroll instead, but you don't need to as you only need the spell prepared. I would probably say you would still need to be able to fill the components (verbal, somatic, and material), and a scroll removes the need for material. So if the spell had an actual material cost, the scroll would be used up rather than the material. But if the spell only needed a material (not consumed or of a gp value), the scroll could remove the need for the material without being used up (as that would only come into play if the caster was missing their component pouch or arcane focus). Of course, the caster still needs the components for the Glyph of Warding spell.

Comment: I believe it has been stated in another question that Spell Glyph does consume 2 spell slots under regular circumstances (although I don't have the link right now), hence the above question.

Comment: My primary hesitation to agree would be the existence of Contingency, which is explicit. Typically the rules are explicit where they can be. Regardless, the spell at least denotes that you must have the spell prepared and must cast the spell in conjunction with Glyph of Warding. Spell scrolls require a spell slot to create, and using it entails casting the spell. So just by that, even if Glyph of Warding requires a spell slot for the second spell, I would say a spell scroll could be used instead. Some may say because it requires the spell to be prepared, it implies you cast it, but I disagree.

Comment: I don't think I understand this answer. The rules state "Once the spell is cast, the words on the scroll fade, and it
crumbles to dust." (DMG, p. 200, post [errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DMG-Errata.pdf) ). It doesn't mention spell slots at all. So I'm not sure why you emphasized them, nor what they have to do with whether or not the scroll is consumed.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme, I empathized spell slots because the spell does not indicate the need for two spell slots to be used for each casting (whereas Contingency does). So you're only using a spell slot for Glyph of Warding. The spell being placed in the Spell Glyph doesn't require a spell slot, and thus must only meet two requirements: the spell must be prepared by the caster of Glyph of Warding, and the caster must be casting the second spell in conjunction. My whole point is that you wouldn't use up a spell scroll at all unless you were doing so to fulfill the material component.

Comment: @Iter This is were I'm confused: casting the spell from the scroll destroys the scroll. So doesn't your second requirement "casting the second spell in conjunction" indicate that the scroll is destroyed?

Comment: It's possible I'm not explaining my thought process well. Basically: you don't need to actually cast the spell (expending the spell slot) as the Glyph of Warding doesn't call for a spell slot to be used. You just use the spell slot for the GoW. Where casting the other spell comes into play is making sure you have the verbal, somatic, and material components for that spell. So you aren't actually casting it, you're just prepping it in a Glyph of Warding. You just need it prepared. From there, I go further to say that if you don't have a material component for the second spell, use the scroll.

Comment: Could you help me out with one more thing then? Where does it specify that you need to "have the verbal, somatic, and material components for that spell"?

Comment: In chapter 10 of the PHB, it goes over how to cast a spell. One requirement is that the components are met. There is also a portion that denotes that when casters cast a spell, they typically have to expend a spell slot. But it goes on to say that it is possible to cast spells without expending a spell slot (from special abilities or items). So the casting of a spell requires components unless the ability says otherwise, and slots are typical of spells cast from casters but not guaranteed. Also, GoW indicates that when cast at higher level slots, the stored spell can be higher as a result.

Comment: @Iter Ok, now I'm really confused. You are saying that the spell scroll doesn't crumble because you didn't cast the spell. But you are also saying that you need to have the verbal, somatic, and material components because that's "how to cast a spell." If you're casting the spell, the scroll should be gone: if you're not, you shouldn't need the components. I'm not sure how you are concluding that you both need the components and retain the scroll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89950/discussion-between-gandalfmeansme-and-iter).