# Does the UA Lore Mastery wizard's Master of Magic feature create a prepared spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, unearthed-arcana, spellcasting

According to the wording of the UA Lore Mastery wizard's capstone, it says:

> At 14th level, your knowledge of magic allows you to duplicate almost any spell. As a bonus action, you can call to mind the ability to cast one spell of your choice from any class' spell list. The spell must be of a level for which you have spell slots, you mustn't have it prepared, and you follow the normal rules for casting it, including expending a spell slot. If the spell isn't a wizard spell, it counts as a wizard spell when you cast it. The ability to cast the spell vanishes from your mind when you cast it or when the current turn ends.
>   You can't use this feature again until you finish a long rest.

For the purposes of a spell like *glyph of warding*'s **Spell Glyph** option, which states that

> You can store a **prepared** spell of 3rd level or lower in the glyph...

would Master of Magic create a "prepared" spell that can be used in this way, or does it create one that's outside the wizard's prepared spell list and unable for *glyph of warding* use?

Would it work in the same way/idea explained here?
[Can you store a Spell Glyph with a spell scroll of a prepared spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141362/can-you-store-a-spell-glyph-with-a-spell-scroll-of-a-prepared-spell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Master of Magic does not prepare the spell

The feature states:

> The spell must be of a level for which you have spell slots, **you mustn't have it prepared**, and you follow the normal rules for casting it, including expending a spell slot.

The spell you choose is not prepared and Master of Magic does not subsequently state that the chosen spell's counts as a prepared spell. Therefore, every spell you cast through Master of Magic is not prepared.

*Glyph of warding*'s Spell Glyph option requires you to cast a prepared spell, so it is incompatible with Master of Magic.

The Master of Magic does state that the chosen spell counts as wizard spell:

> If the spell isn't a wizard spell, it counts as a wizard spell when you cast it.

But a wizard spell is not always a prepared spell.

Answer (score -2):

### Maybe, but it can't be used for *Glyph of Warding* even if it does

That's because the *Glyph* takes 1 hour to cast, and the spell chosen for the Lore Mastery wizard's Master of Magic feature only lasts to the end of your current turn. So, even if it does count as prepared, it's not prepared for the required time.

Comment: Fair point. Depends on if the DMs in my server would allow using a bonus action during spellcasting, but that's definitely not RAW, I don't think.