# How much damage can a character deal in a single round using a ranged weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, ranged-attack

**Rules and restrictions:**

1. Spells are allowed, as long as it doesn't deal damage on their own (e.g shooting one arrow and using your bonus action to deal damage with a Blade of Disaster);
2. Damage can't be dealt to the character him/herself or any of his/her allies, although, since it's theoretical, something that has a **chance** to harm them, but can also damage enemies **is allowed**;
3. There is not an specific limit to the number of targets, if you need a lot, you may have them, as long as the number doesn't go too far (such as in 500 tiny flying creatures for Ranger's Volley);
   *NOTE: Please clarify how much damage each target will be taking*
4. Again, not an specific limit to how many teammates you may have, but stacking a buff from an certain build is **not allowed**;
5. Separating the damage in 3 categories would be much appreciated, although not needed, as just showing each step during damage calculations is enough:
   1st. No magic items, boons nor other buffs;
   2nd. With magic items and boons, no other buffs;
   3rd. Everything included.
6. Only official content is allowed, and anything else not covered in these limits can be assumed to be allowed

Comment: For the purposes of this question, HOW MANY ranged weapons can you use? Also, welcome to the Stack!

Comment: How many teammates are allowed to boost your damage? How many targets?

Comment: As a side not, you may want to consider adding some restrictions. I can think of two ways immediately to do unbounded damage in one round with how this is worded currently. Consider looking over [this question about something similar](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115624/41726) for inspiration on how to properly restrict the question to receive better answers. (obviously you can do different restrictions, but that may advise what to consider)

Comment: Strongly related: [What is the most damage that can be done with a single ranged attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149669/what-is-the-most-damage-that-can-be-done-in-a-single-ranged-attack)

Comment: @TieflingDragon84 I mean... can you use more than 2? If you can, than sure, it's allowed. I want to impose the lowest amount of restrictions as possible, doesn't really matter if it's impractical. Also, thanks! Btw, I'll answer the rest of the comments later, I'm kinda busy now

Comment: @DavidCoffron These edits might do the job, I think.

Comment: What is meant by 'stacking a buff from a certain build' in rule 4?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical come to think of it, I might need to rephrase it to make it clearer. I meant that repeating a process multiple times to stack a buff (from a similar source) is not allowed.

Comment: @Farlitz that still seems unclear. Are you intending to reference some cheese strats like stacking beneficial properties from artifacts? If so, you may want to include an example of what's not permitted.

Comment: Also, how should stats be determined? Can we just assume 20's across the board? Or should it be 30's since Tomes are official content and allow you to get up to 30?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical yeah, I just don't know how to put it exactly. I just wanted to avoid "infinite" damage loops, such as those David Coffron mentioned on one of the answers. Also, rule #6 states just that, your stats can be 30.

Comment: Since no one "contested" David Coffron's answer, I guess I'll be accepting his answer as correct. I'll keep researching to see if I can find anything not included there, but it seems complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**With all the buffs we can exceed 20,000 average damage, but let's start at the beginning:**

## With no buffs

**1,043.75 average damage [1,709 max]**

### Bugbear Gunner

Our archer for the no buff, no magic version is a Bugbear Fighter (Battle Master) 12/Rogue (Assassin) 5/Ranger (Gloom Stalker) 3 with a [hunting rifle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#AdventuringOptions) and purple worm poison on each bullet. Our allies are an 14th level Fighter (Battle Master), a 7th level Paladin (Oath of the Sentinel), a 6th level Warlock (The Fiend), and a 2nd level Wizard (Chronurgy Magic). This provides the following damage elements:

- 4 attacks per action via Extra Attack and Dread Ambusher.
- Action Surge to take the Attack action again.
- 1 attack via Commander's Strike
- These 9 shots are possible since we can reload our hunting rifle once with our bonus action.
- 5 ASIs for the Athlete, Gunner, Martial Adept, Piercer, and Sharpshooter feats
- 7 d10 Superiority Dice (5 from levels, 1 from Superior Technique, 1 from Martial Adept)
- 1d12 extra from the Commander's Strike
- 2 Sneak Attacks (3d6 each)
- 2 Dread Ambusher Attacks (1d6 each)
- 9 Surprise Attacks (2d6 each); our Paladin, Warlock, and Wizard help us go first
- Every attack is a critical hit from Assassinate
- One die gets rerolled with Piercer
- Purple Worm Poison damage (doesn't benefit from the critical hit)

Altogether, our average damage is as follows:

$$9*((1*6.75)+(4*5.5)+(4*3.5)+(12*3.5)+10+5)+7*(2*5.5)+2*(6*3.5+2*3.5)+1*(2*6.5) = 1043.75$$

## With magic items and boons

**1,889.75 average damage [3,203 max]**

### The Oathbow

The previous build essentially works as is with one deviation: we replace our hunter rifle with an *oathbow*, use *arrows of slaying* and attune to the *Book of Exalted Deeds* and the *Eye of Vecna* for 3 major beneficial properties of 1d6 extra damage each. This changes our base damage from our weapon from 2d10 to 6d10 + 1d8 + 3d6 and gives 3d6 extra damage per attack.

As such, here is our average damage:

$$9*((1*6.75)+(11*5.5)+(3*4.5)+(6*3.5)+(6*3.5)+(4*3.5)+(12*3.5)+10+5)+7*(2*5.5)+2*(6*3.5+2*3.5)+1*(2*6.5) = 1889.75$$

## With the buffs

**23,668 average damage [40,768 max]**

### The Characters

If we are able to use buffs, a different build is in order. We should now be a Duergar and here are the classes of our new build:

- Fighter (Eldritch Knight) 3 ---------------------------------------------------------- for Superior Technique, Action Surge, and the wizard spell list
- Rogue (Assassin) 17 --------------------------------------------- for Assassinate, the Martial Adept, Metamagic Adept, Piercer, and Sharpshooter feats, and Death Strike

...here are our magic weapons:

- longbow
- *Book of Exalted Deeds*
- *Eye of Vecna*
- *Hand of Vecna*
- *sword of the paruns*
- 14 *arrows of slaying*
- *potion of giant size*
- 3 *spell scrolls of shapechange*

...and here are our allies:

- 14x Clerics (Grave Domain) 2 ---------------------------------------- for Path to the Grave
- Bard (College of Valor) 18 -------------------------------------------- for Combat Inspiration, the spells *wish* and *simulacrum* via Magical Secrets
- Bard (College of Lore) 18/Fighter 2 ---------------------------------- for *glyph of warding*, the spells *banishing smite, branding smite, elemental weapon, flame arrows, simulacrum, spirit shroud, and wish* via Magical Secrets, Action Surge, and the Boon of High Magic
- Bard (College of Lore) 18/Fighter 2 ---------------------------------- for *glyph of warding*, the spells *divine favor, enlarge/reduce, haste, holy weapon, simulacrum, Tenser's transformation, and wish* via Magical Secrets, Action Surge, and the Boon of High Magic
- Fighter (Eldritch Knight) 17 ------------------------------------------- for Action Surge x2, the wizard spell list, the Metamagic Adept feat, and Combat Inspiration
- Bard (College of Valor) 15 --------------------------------------------- for Combat Inspiration
- Fighter (Eldritch Knight) 17 ------------------------------------------- for Action Surge x2, the wizard spell list, and the Metamagic Adept feat
- Bard (College of Valor) 15 --------------------------------------------- for Combat Inspiration
- Bard (College of Valor) 15/Cleric (Order Domain) 1/Fighter 2 --- for Combat Inspiration, Voice of Authority, and Action Surge
- Bard (College of Valor) 15 --------------------------------------------- for Combat Inspiration
- Fighter (Battle Master) 10/Bard (College of Valor) 10 ------------- for Commander's Strike and Combat Inspiration
- Bard (College of Valor) 15 --------------------------------------------- for Combat Inspiration
- Fighter 6 ----------------------------------------------------------------- for the Squire of Solamnia and Knight of the Crown feats

### The Procedure

1. The first Grave Domain cleric uses Path to the Grave on the target.
2. The 13 other Grave Domain cleric Readies Path to the Grave for after our Duergar attacks.
3. Our 18th level Valor Bard gives Bardic Inspiration to our Duergar
4. Our 18th level Valor Bard then casts *wish* replicating the effects of *simulacrum* targeting one of the Lore Bards.
5. Each new simulacrum casts *wish* replicating the effects of *glyph of warding* to store
6. Each new *simulacrum* then uses Action Surge to cast *wish* replicating the effects of *simulacrum* targeting one of the Lore Bards
7. This is done until we have 35 spell glyphs with the following spells: 14x *banishing smites*, 14x 8th level *branding smites, 7th level elemental weapon, 7th level spirit shroud, divine favor, enlarge, haste, holy weapon, and Tenser's transformation*
8. The final simulacrum uses Action Surge to cast *flame arrows* at 5th level on our Duergar's quiver
9. One of the Lore Bards administers the *potion of giant strength* to our Duergar
10. Our Duergar uses a *spell scroll of shapechange* with the Quicken Spell Metamagic to turn into a Marilith and then takes the Attack action three times
11. Both Eldritch Knights use a *spell scroll of shapechange* with the Quicken Spell Metamagic to turn into either a duergar warlord, or a duergar mind master
12. Both Eldritch Knights then use Call to Attack or Mind Mastery respectively
13. Both Eldritch Knights then use Action Surge to Ready those same actions for the following turns
14. On those proceeding turns, two of our 15th level Valor Bards give Bardic Inspiration to our Duergar before the Eldritch Knight actions
15. Our Order Domain cleric gives Bardic Inspiration to the Duergar and then casts a spell on the Duergar using Voice of Authority
16. Our Order Domain cleric then uses Action Surge to Ready a spell for the purpose of Voice of Authority on the following turn
17. On that proceeding turn, one of our 15th level Valor Bards give Bardic Inspiration to our Duergar before the Order Domain cleric action
18. Our Battle Master gives Bardic Inspiration to our Duergar and then uses Commander's Strike
19. Our final 15th level Valor Bard (who is attuned to a *sword of the paruns*) gives Bardic Inspiration to our Duergar and then uses the first property of the sword on the Duergar
20. Our Knight of the Crown grants one last attack to our Duergar

### The Calculation

Here are the damage elements with all the buffs:

- 2 base attacks from to *Tenser's transformation*; 2 more attacks from Action Surge; 1 more attack from *haste*
- 9 reaction attacks from 2x Call to Attack, 2x Mind Mastery, 2x Voice of Authority, Commander's Strike, *sword of the paruns*, and Knight of the Crown
- Each attack does a base damage of 3d8 + 6d10 + 5 with longbow, *arrow of slaying*, and *potion of giant's strength*
- Each attack has the following source of extra damage:

  - *branding smite* for 5d10
  - 8th level *branding smite* for 8d6
  - 7th level *elemental weapon* for 3d4 + 3
  - 7th level *spirit shroud* for 3d8
  - *divine favor* for 1d4
  - *enlarge* for 1d4
  - *holy weapon* for 2d8
  - *Tenser's transformation* for 2d12
  - *flame arrows* for 1d6
  - Major Beneficial artifact properties for 4d6
  - Sharpshooter for 10
- 10 attacks benefit from Sneak Attack for 9d6
- 6 attacks benefit from 15th level Combat Inspiration for 1d12
- 2 attacks benefit from Superiority Dice for 1d6
- 1 attack benefits from the following sources of extra damage:

  - 10th level Combat Inspiration for 1d10
  - Commander's Strike for 1d10
- We reroll one damage die per attack from Piercer
- Every attack is a critical hit from Assassinate (and Piercer grants an extra d8)
- Damage per attack is quadrupled with Path to the Grave and Death Strike
- 14 doses of Purple Worm Poison

Here is the full calculation (dice stacked to take up less space):

$$4*(14*((1*8)+(3*6.5)+(22*5.5)+(17*4.5)+(26*3.5)+(10*2.5)+10+5+3)+10*(18*3.5)+6*(2*6.5)+2*(2*3.5)+1*(4*5.5))+14*(12*3.5) = 23668$$

*Note: This relies pretty heavily on turn order. You can force the turns to take a specific order with sufficient quantity of Divination wizards using Portent*

Comment: I didn't want to bog down the answer further, but if your DM rules that you can't quicken a spell scroll, you get 4 less attacks and 2 less sneak attacks resulting in 17,252 average damage

Comment: Poison does not stack.  You only get it on the first attack on a creature.

Comment: @SamLacrumb I don't know of any rules that indicate that. What makes you think that?

Comment: Read the rules on poison. Additional doses just add disadvantage to saves.

Comment: @SamLacrumb That is not a rule.

Comment: @SamLacrumb Each attack can apply the poison separately. The only time it doesn't stack is if you applied multiple doses to the same attack. There is no rule related to disadvantage to saves. There's something similar in Pathfinder, but nothing like that in D&D 5e

Comment: For the 'Bugbear Gunner' build, how are you getting to 10 attacks? I'm only counting 7 attacks (3 normal + 3 Action Surge + 1 Commander's Strike).

Comment: @RayofLight Extra Attack (at that level) makes each Attack action "contain" three small-a attacks. This argues the Action Surges make it possible to take the Attack action thrice: there's 9 attacks. Commander's Strike for the tenth.

Comment: @nitsua60 That wouldn't work, though, since you can only action surge once on a single turn. Even if you're getting the Commander's Strike attack off-turn, you wouldn't be able to action surge twice in the span of 1 round required by the question, since it has to be used on your turn.

Comment: @RayofLight I completely missed that limitation. I'll adjust; shows how little I play high level fighters.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with.

Assume we have surprise first round.

My buffing friends are a lv 20 Lore college Bard, and a Lv 20 Genie Warlock.
The bard will be using Glyph of Warding to load the warlocks Genie bottle with the following buffing spells:

- Spirit Shroud lv 9 slot 4d8/att
- Haste: +1 Att
- Swift Quiver: +2 att on bonus action
- Magic Weapon: +3    dam
- Divine Favor: 1d4/Att
- Banishing smite: 5d10
- Branding smite: 9d6

Our sniper will be a Lv4 rogue assassin, lv4 Gloom Stalker Lv12 Fighter Battle master.
Stats: 20 Dex, all other stats meet minimum requirements for multi-class.

Feats: (human 1, ranger 1, rogue 1, fighter 4)

- Sharpshooter: +10 damage
- Martial Adept: (gain one superiority die)
- Piercer: Add 1 damage die on crit, +1 Dex
- Poisoner: ignore resistance to poison
- Dex +2
- Alert: +5 Initiative
- Lucky: re-roll 3/day

Fighting style:

- Archery: +2 to hit
- Fighting Initiate: Gain one superiority die

Total attacks in one round: 11

- Gloom Stalker:  +2 attacks, +2d8,
- Assassin:  +2d6, all hits are crits
- Fighter: +3 attacks, action surge +3 attacks, Superiority dice:d10s,
  5 (total 7)

Total Attacks from classes: 8
Total attacks from spells:3 (Haste, Swift Quiver)

Set up: No Magic Items

Round one, Warlock brings you into his bottle with an action.  you use a free action to say the command word and are fully buffed.  Warlock then casts you out as a bonus action.

You attack.

11 total attacks, 7 with superiority dice, 2 with dread ambusher dice (ranger) all with sneak attack, all crits.

Attacks:
Bow: 1d8(Long bow),1d4(Divine Favor), 4d8(Spirit shroud), 1d8(piercer)

= 6d8+1d4= X 11

77-572 Assuming all hit.

Additional damage:

5d10(Banishing smite), 9d6(Branding Smite), 2d8(Gloomstalker), 7d10(superiority dice)
2d6(sneak attack)

12d10+11d6+2d8=

25-202

Sub total:

102-774

X2 for crit:

204-1548

Plus static damage:
+3(Magic), +5(Dex), +10(Sharpshooter) X11 = 198

402-1746

Average Damage: 1074  (no Magic Items)

Notes:

Purple Worm Poison 12d6 (not magical)

414-1818

Avg:  1116 Damage

Comment: Actually I think the no stacking buffs from the same build covers both of the infinite damages I came up with (*wish simulacrum* loop and *time stop* loop). If you have another infinite damage option please post another answer because I'd love to see it. :)

Comment: If your first paragraph isn't relevant anymore, please remove - otherwise please support it! May also help to put your final total as a lede.

Comment: You only get sneak attack once per turn, so all attacks can't have it.

Comment: Great list! I did want to add that since [you need to spend two spell slots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/105624/30218) (of the appropriate level) for Glyph of Warding, a Level 20 Lore Bard would need some extra feature (such as an epic boon) to store a level 9 spell in such a Glyph (since a Bard would otherwise only have one 9th level spell slot available). But most of this looks solid to me! The one other thing I wondered about is what the point of the genie’s bottle was. Surely, this could just as easily be cast on a wall?

Comment: *Hex* and *hunter's mark* would either target the archer, or benefit the ally when cast via *glyph of warding*

Comment: You also can't be invisible and benefit from *branding smite* at the same time

Comment: Your archer has a very high initiative bonus of +11 (DEX mod + Alert + WIS mod), yet your method seems entirely dependent upon the warlock acting _before_ the archer on round 1. Attacking before the warlock's action means no buffs, waiting until round 2 to attack loses surprise and gloom stalker attack.

Comment: -1, while this is a good start, there are too many errors in it.

Comment: I think i resolved most issues.